# Making Relations in a model class with code first Entiy framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am using asp.net mvc and for data part , I am using code first method and I have a model class called 'Comment' . I want to implement nested comments(I want to have the reply option) . Here is my model class :

```
 public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    public int PostID { get; set; }

    //if it is null (or zero) , it is a father comment
    //if it is not null , it is a boy comment
    public int ParentID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نام")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(200)]

    public string CommentName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ایمیل")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد کنید")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(200)]

    public string CommentEmail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "متن نظر")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نظر خودرا بنویسید")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCommentOk { get; set; }

    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
    public virtual Lis<Comment> Comment2 { get; set; }
    public Comment()
    {

    }
}
```

I want to make a relation between 'ParrentID' and 'CommentID' . if ParentID is 0 , it is normal comment but if it is not zero it is replying comment and its value shows the commentID of its parent comment.I implemented the idea using this code :

```
        public virtual Comment Comment1 { get; set; }
        public virtual List<Comment> Comment2 { get; set; }
```

but this does not work . What is the problem and what is the solutin?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }

    .....

    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    
     public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }
}
```

and add this to db  your db context

```
public class Context: DbContext 
{

    public DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
        
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Parent)
            .WithMany(m => m.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentID);
    }
}
```

Comment: how should I add the the second part of your code into my db context? there is no function!

Comment: @MohammadYoosefiyan Check my  updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Here look below I tried to comment and make it as simple as possible so you can understand.

Why I did it this way is so that you wont need to add extra configuration as @Serge did. This is what make `ORM` most useful

```cs
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int CommentID { get; set; }
    
    // here to you dont need this, as long as you have post, post_Id will be created 
    // public int PostID { get; set; }
    
    // As long as it has children then this is a parent of children
    // Parent_Id will be automaticly created in the db, 
    // so you dont need to add it here
    // so when you save an item with children, those children will automaticly inherit 
    // the current id.
    public virtual List<Comment> Children { get; set; }
    
    public virtual Comment Parent { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "نام")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نام خود را وارد کنید")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(200)]

    public string CommentName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "ایمیل")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا ایمیل خود را وارد کنید")]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [MaxLength(200)]

    public string CommentEmail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "متن نظر")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "لطفا نظر خودرا بنویسید")]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string CommentText { get; set; }
    public DateTime CommentDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsCommentOk { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public Comment()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I did not understand why you are removing postID . how you can handle things when you do not know that a specific comment belongs to which post??. would you explain a little more?

Comment: I have worked and Build a Library `EntityWorker.Core` So I know about ORM very much. It all depend about what you really want and how you would like your class  to look like. Those ForgenKey gets created automatically and dose not need to be added. But you can also add them if you like but you will have to use @Serge solution for that. read more here about EntityFramework, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?tabs=fluent-api%2Cfluent-api-simple-key%2Csimple-key